# Other Android Developer Tools

Tags: java, android

The Android SDK comes with many tools to help you develop application, I am wonder what else is out there.

One tool that I have found is coloredlogcat - http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/

Answer (score 6):

The Android Asset Studio is great for building icon images.  Very handy.

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of more webbased tools I know of like:

[DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) which helps you creating layouts
[RadDroid](http://raddroid.com/) which helps you with the initial set-up of your project.

This website also features some of the best Android developer tools:
http://www.web3mantra.com/2011/05/05/best-android-developer-tools-and-resources/

Answer (score 1):

The [Android Icon Maker](http://www.redrails.com.br/2011/09/android-icon-maker) can also be very useful, him create a set of the icons for Android Applications from a specific icon.